# MySQL - With two options in query, can one be a 'must have' and the other be 'optional'?

Tags: mysql

Apologies for question title, if anyone can explain it better please do edit. 
I have a MySQL select statement (which I am running through Perl dbi) like below:

```
select skills from my_table where (skills like '%maths%' or skills like '%english%');
```

This will run, but it chooses either skills like 'maths' OR skills like 'english'. 
I would like to have it so it definitely finds 'maths', and maybe finds 'english' if that makes sense.

I think of it kind of like when you have `and`, where it only returns results with those elements. So if I had done:

```
select skills from my_table where (skills like '%maths%' and skills like '%english%');
```

it would have returned results with BOTH skills.

So what I want is a combination of both sqls if that is possible, with the 'maths' being a definite find, and the 'english' being optional. I hope I have explained this properly... any help appreciated!

Edit: okay, maybe I do need to clarify... if there is an option for 'english' I want it to be found, but if there isn't I want it to still pick up options for 'maths', but if there are no 'maths' options, then I want it to return nothing. So it is not just one or the other.

Comment: how will you provide the option for english?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to ask about... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the `keyField` for all rows with maths skills, as well as an additional column to show whether or not they also have english skills.

```
select   keyField,  
        'Maths' mathsSkill,
        CASE WHEN skills LIKE '%english%' THEN 'English' else 'No English' END englishSkill
from    my_table 
where   skills like '%maths%'
```

Comment: oohh this looks like what I want! Thanks, I'll try that out +1

Comment: this is actually awesome! not the format I want, but I'm sure I can manipulate it - perfect

Answer (score 1):

`I would like to have it so it definitely finds 'maths', and maybe finds 'english' if that makes sense.` what do you mean by if that makes sense.

I think you just need to do following

```
select skills from my_table where (skills like '%maths%')
```

Answer (score 1):

But if 'english is optional' you can simply remove it :

```
select skills 
from my_table 
where skills like '%maths%'
```

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
select skills from my_table where skills like '%maths%';
```

This will give records with maths.. Since English is optional , you need not provide it